# is it possible to break a loop with an event in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, mouseevent

I couldn't find anything online but how do I make a function run until a certain event (ex. mousemove or mouseup) is fired? like something like this:

```js
@HostListener('window:mousedown', ['$event'])
onMouseDown(): void {
    while (true) {
        // do stuff
        if(mouseUpEvent || mouseMoveEvent) { // <-- how do I exit the loop when either mouseUp or mouseMove fires?
            return;
        }
    }
}
@HostListener('window:mouseup', ['$event'])
onMouseUp() : void {
    // do stuff
}
@HostListener('window:mousemove', ['$event'])
onMouseMove() : void {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Observables. Update a `BehaviorSubject` when the mouse event occurs, and listen to changes in the respective `BehaviorSubject`. That way you would be able to chain the different events using rxjs.

```js
mouseDown$ = new BehaviorSubject<void>();
mouseUp$ = new BehaviorSubject<void>();
mouseMove$ = new BehaviorSubject<void>(),

listenToMouseEvents(): void {
  this.mouseDown$.pipe(
    takeUntil(merge(this.mouseUp$, this.mouseMove$)),  // conditions to stop the the observable
    repeat()  // so it doesn't kill the observable
  ).subscribe(() => {
     // do stuff
  })
}

@HostListener('window:mousedown', ['$event'])
onMouseDown(): void {
  this.mouseDown$.next();
}
@HostListener('window:mouseup', ['$event'])
onMouseUp() : void {
  this.mouseUp$.next();
}
@HostListener('window:mousemove', ['$event'])
onMouseMove() : void {
  this.mouseMove$.next();
}
```

Comment: I ended up using something similar to this code but with a timer that stops when mouseup or mousemove is called, will post the code when I have time. Thanks!